# Move a pattern from after a string to before

Tags: regex, scripting, grep

I have a large codebase to sort through, so I'd like to automate the process as much as possible. I've already managed to grep out all the lines that are relevant to my task, but I'd like to automate the task itself.

What I'm trying to do is change all trailing increments to leading increments, as in the following example:

```
i++;
```

becomes

```
++i;
```

I imagine that regexes will be involved, and I'm rather rusty with those. Also, which language would be best for scripting this? I'm working on Windows 7 x64 at the moment, but a platform-agnostic solution would be cool. Also, if you could point me to any specific resources for learning more about this type of problem, that would be awesome.

Comment: This sounds purely evil... and you'll probably break your code... but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it...

```
s/([a-z0-9]+)\+\+/++$1/g
```

But it's evil, and will break things like:

```
print "+++++++++Some heading++++++++++++\n";
```

Not to mention the cases where i++ and ++i actually do different things, and you need to use i++.

My suggestion (assuming you actually have some real reason to think that i++ is wrong in many cases):

```
rgrep ++ * > fixme.txt
```

Then open `fixme.txt` in your favorite text editor, and manually investigate each occurrence, removing it from the text file as you go.

Comment: Probably meant ``\+\+`` not ``\+\_``.

Comment: Thanks! I figured I might have to end up doing this manually, but I was interested to see how it would work anyways

Answer (score 0):

First, see [[13.15] Which is more efficient: i++ or ++i?](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/operator.html#fqa-13.15)  For primitive types like `int`, there is no gain in efficiency.  Assuming you know this, however, the solution depends on what tool you'll use.  If you were using Perl, i.e.

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/search/replace/g;' *.cc
```

...then this regex would work:

```
s/\b([a-zA-Z]\w*)\+\+/\+\+$1/g
```

I agree with @Flimzy though that this seems extremely dangerous and should not be automated.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before with projects. It's a fine idea *provided you have your code base in a repository*. Conveniently, that allows you to run the change, then get a project diff dumped into your favorite text editor to see what all changed. A quick look will let you see if anything unexpected got edited, and you can fix it back.

Besides using the regex Flimzy suggested, the other option is to build a tiny lexer/parser to fit this use case. You aren't looking for a full blown compiler, just something that has sufficient states for comments and quotes.

[Lex&Yacc 2nd. Ed.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920002.do) has an example lexer for reading c code which is quite small, demonstrating the power of this tool chain. I believe that the examples are available elsewhere as well. If it seems to complex, you can fake it with a simple state machine and regex system built with a perl script.

Finally, you can also check out [ply](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/), if you'd rather use python.